# Column filter for "empty" value

Tags: ag-grid

Is there a way to add a column filter for empty values?
I see we can filter for equal, not equal, ... but I'd like to have an option to filter a column so it returns rows where the column is empty or null.

Comment: You can also use plain javascript to set the [filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-provided-simple/#example-simple-filters). So, maybe something like `if(value == ''){ // do something}`?

Comment: In options is also a ["empty"](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-provided-simple/#filterOptions)

Comment: @Rene the empty options means something different according to this https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-provided-simple/#filterOptions

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood it. :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue with empty cells
You should use 'Blank option'

```
const filterOptions = [
    'empty',
    {
        displayKey: 'blanks',
        displayName: 'Blanks',
        test: function (filterValue, cellValue) {
            return cellValue == undefined;
        },
        hideFilterInput: true,
    },
    'equals',
    'notEqual',
    'lessThan',
    'lessThanOrEqual',
    'greaterThan',
    'greaterThanOrEqual',
    'inRange'
];

columnDef = [
    {
        headerName: 'someValue', field: 'someValue',
        filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
        filterParams: {
            filterOptions: filterOptions
        }
    },]
```

`'empty'` - is equal to 'Please choose option'

more inforamtion you can find here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-provided-simple/#blank-cells-date-and-number-filters

Comment: Thank you, will check this one. Looks like a good candidate for what we need

Comment: @vmasanas any progress?

Comment: Sorry for the delay on approving the answer. That was exactly what we needed. Thanks

Comment: The meaning of 'empty' was leading me astray - this cleared it up thanks.

Comment: The Aggrid doc is seriously confusing! We can add more than 1 additional item, for example we could have "blank" and "not blank" just by duplicating the code shown above and updating the rule accordingly.

Comment: This worked for me, in newer versions test and hideFilterInput have changed: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-provided-simple/?#custom-filter-options